# how to develop a custom equilizer for media player in android?

Tags: android, media-player, media, android-mediaplayer, equalizer

I am developing app related to music player, its having equalizer settings, i know every device having a default equalizer. code for getting the default equalizer

```
 equilizer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent i = new Intent(AudioEffect.ACTION_DISPLAY_AUDIO_EFFECT_CONTROL_PANEL);
            i.putExtra(AudioEffect.EXTRA_AUDIO_SESSION, mp.getAudioSessionId());
            startActivityForResult(i, 11113);
        }
    });
}
```

In onActivityResult:

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        return;
    }


}
```

Using the above code we can get default equalizer, but my requirement is  design a equalizer with different UI and add some more effects to the equalizer.

Can any one give me an idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

There is an [`Equalizer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html) effect. You can pass the audio session ID of the `MediaPlayer` to its constructor:

```
// Given a MediaPlayer mp
Equalizer eq = new Equalizer(0, mp.getAudioSessionId());
```

[Here](http://androidcluster.blogspot.jp/2012/02/mediaplayer-with-visualization-and.html) is an example program that uses it. I haven't built it to see, but it at least hooks up the equalizer correctly.

Comment: how do we pass the currently playing mp3 file in one activity of media player to another activity of eqaulizer

Comment: You should probably have the `MediaPlayer` in a `Service`, then have an `Activity` or `Fragment` for controlling playback and an `Activity` or `Fragment` for the equalizer. If you want more specific advice, ask a question and post some code.